# eclipse tomcat starts application too fast, but it doesn't actually starts

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat

I'm trying to run my application that used to run nicely. On Eclipse, I'm using Tomcat for development and the console output for starting the working application used to be in the neighborhood of 8000+ ms. Now its startup time is close to 2000 ms, but the application does not run.

As I am posting this question, I got a 403 error from the browser.

The only thing I did that was less than usual was trying to open the project on Intellij IDEA. Though I understand there are a loto of benefits for this IDE, I am too much used to eclipse.

I'm reviewing the code to see if I get the problem solved, but I'm running out of ideas.

What might I be missing?

Comment: Any warning/error logs ?

Comment: Nope, nothing that might suggest what's wrong.

Comment: No offense, but I don't trust you (I don't trust anyone, only logs).

Comment: No offense taken. I'll look up the tomcat logs and post to the question.

Comment: Fiddling around, I right-clicked the project > Configure > Convert to Maven Project. And voilà! All good now!